# ValueError: cannot set a frame with no defined index and a scalar Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've this code to filter and add a new column with more info but I've this error: "ValueError: cannot set a frame with no defined index and a scalar" when execute the .loc function

```
temp_strongest_impulse = resultdf[resultdf['Impulse_ATR'] >= strongest_impulse]

res_Strongest_GapUp = temp_strongest_impulse[temp_strongest_impulse['Gap'] == '']
res_Strongest_GapUp.loc[temp_strongest_impulse['Gap'] == '','Strongest GAP'] = ''
res_Strongest_GapDown = temp_strongest_impulse[temp_strongest_impulse['Gap'] == '']
res_Strongest_GapDown.loc[temp_strongest_impulse['Gap'] == '','Strongest GAP'] = ''
```

Any idea to solve it? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey just went thought the Segment. The issue is in usage of

> loc()

Corrected Segment:

```
temp_strongest_impulse = resultdf[resultdf['Impulse_ATR'] >= strongest_impulse]
res_Strongest_GapUp = temp_strongest_impulse[temp_strongest_impulse['Gap'] == '']
res_Strongest_GapUp['Strongest GAP'] = ''

res_Strongest_GapDown = temp_strongest_impulse[temp_strongest_impulse['Gap'] == '']
res_Strongest_GapDown['Strongest GAP'] = ''
```

For res_Strongest_GapUp am assigning '' to the new column 'Strongest GAP' directly. This will set the value '' for all rows in res_Strongest_GapUp. Similarly for res_Strongest_GapDown '' is assigned to the new column 'Strongest GAP'.

Comment: Thanks a lot @arunbh, I think I'm exhausted for today and the tiredness doesn't let me think clearly.

Comment: Take a look this segment, I've error too:                                            
    res_Strongest_ERC = temp_strongest_impulse[abs(temp_strongest_impulse['Value_ERC']) >= erc_min] 
    res_Strongest_ERC.loc[res_Strongest_ERC['ERC'] == '','Strongest ERC'] = ''
    res_Strongest_ERC.loc[res_Strongest_ERC['ERC'] == '','Strongest ERC'] = ''

Comment: Yes great the issue is resolved using loc() :)

Comment: I've the same "ValueError: cannot set a frame with no defined index and a scalar" error message with this segment. I've some similar segments in my app. But not all I can solve with your first appointment.